# Writing vba code in sas

Tags: vba, excel, sas, sas-macro

**I want to implement my VBA code into my SAS-code, so I can do the whole process with one run.**  My SAS code reads a big SAS table, does some transformations, and finally exportes to an Excel file (the code is below). I also wrote some VBA code in the Excel file (for example AutoFiltering for some variables, you can see the code below).

The table looks like this:

```
A B C Var1 Var2 Var3
--------------------
1 1 1 10 15 20
1 1 2 15 20 30
1 2 1 20 30 40
1 2 2 30 40 50
2 1 1 40 50 60
2 1 2 50 60 70
2 2 1 60 70 80
..............
..............
```

However, **I want to implement my VBA code into my SAS-code, so I can do the whole process with one run.** I know how to open and run an Excel file in SAS (the code is below), but I don't know how to implement a VBA code in my SAS.

If you wonder why I want to implement my Macro-code in my SAS, I will work with similar SAS-tables many times in the future, so it would be more practicle to keep the whole-code in one place.

I just realized that I can't export an table in SAS in macro-enabled Excel format, XLSM. I guess it is also a challange. Also, it is not so practicle to save a Macro-code from an Excel file, because it must be saved in Adds-in menu. So it would be much better to handle the whole process in one place, like inside the SAS editor.

THE code in SAS which exports the final table to an Excel file:

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=File1
        OUTFILE= "&server\&env\test1.xlsx" 
        DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE; 
   SHEET="sheet1"; 
RUN;
```

The VBA code example in the Excel file to create AutoFilter for variables in the Excel file:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim ary(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        ary(i) = .Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End With

Range("A1:F20").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$20").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

The code in SAS to start and run an Excel file in SAS:

```
OPTIONS NOXWAIT NOXSYNC;
   DATA _NULL_;
   RC=SYSTEM('START EXCEL');
   RC=SLEEP(0.5);
RUN;
FILENAME CMDS DDE 'EXCEL|SYSTEM';
DATA _NULL_;
   FILE CMDS;
   PUT "[OPEN(""&server\&env\test1.XLS"")]";
   PUT '[RUN("Macro1")]';
   PUT '[SAVE.AS("&server\&env\FORMATTED_FILE.XLSM")';
   PUT "[QUIT()]";
RUN;
QUIT;
```

Comment: You're saying that you want to be able to create a new Excel file via DDE and then create a new VBA macro in it programatically via SAS?

Comment: Basically, Yes. I want that my SAS code will read a SAS-table, export the result to an Excel file (XLSM if possible) and my SAS-code will also run some VBA-code to make the Excel file more beautiful.
and I want that all those processes will be with only one run in only one code...

Comment: Is the excel macro you're running always the same?  Would a method using an excel template work?  I think that's the standard way to do this; you store the excel macro in a 'template' workbook that is static, and execute it from there (while writing to a different workbook, or you can write to the template workbook and then SAVE AS a different workbook name).

Comment: I was planning to use the VBA in SAS for same table variables, but with changing data in each excel file. I would do only changes in "macro variables" at the beginning of the SAS file with %let var1=&var.

You mean saving the Excel Macro as a static template workbook, you mean the XLSB format? and do you mean that I just simply save my Macro-code in any tamplate, and I copy-paste it whenever I need it?

Comment: If your example is autofilter I would argue that Tagsets provides a great mechanism for doing that already.  Also, you can export to XLSM, I've done it may times. What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: You can just save it as any template (any .XLSM), and then *open* the template workbook, and then execute the macro from it.  I don't use template in the official Excel Template sense, just in the "a workbook you're using to start off with"

Comment: @Reeza, it is the 9.2 version, I searched it before, i think it is not possible in this version. I got error when I tried to export to xlsm.

Comment: If you're using DDE why not export with DDE anyways?

Comment: You can always use a VBScript file and call that using `x` (assuming you're on Windows).  If you need to pass parameters you can do that as part of the `x` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to do this is to use a template file.  You have your template saved, which has the excel macro saved in it (and perhaps also has some of the formatting done to it; using DDE you don't have to start with a blank worksheet, after all).

You can either use DDE to populate the template workbook/worksheet, and then "Save As" another file, or you can use DDE to create a new workbook and worksheet, open the template workbook, run the macro, close the template.  Which you do may depend on whether you want to distribute the macro along with your results.

This allows you to run everything without interacting with it in any way - you don't have to add a new macro to it or anything, since the template macro already exists.  Everything can be done in one run this way.

This is shown for example in the paper [Step-by-Step in Using SAS® DDE to Create an Excel Graph Based on N
Observations from a SAS Data Set](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/154-31.pdf), as well as several other papers on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found DDE to be a bit clunky and it gets upset if you touch the excel workbook while its running. This example writes a VBscript to sas workspace then executes iut. Basically you can get the put statements to write code for whatever you want the program to do and it can be driven by whats in a SAS dataset. This example adds a header and foter to an existing excel spreadsheet...

```
%macro xlHeadFoot(WorkBookPath=,Header=FileName,Footer=SheetName,onlySheet=);

  %local _shortpath WorkBook;

  data _null_;
    length header footer $200;
    header=ifc(lowcase("&header.")='filename' or lowcase("&header.")='sheetname',tranwrd(tranwrd(lowcase("&header."),'filename','&F'),'sheetname','&A'),"&header.");
    footer=ifc(lowcase("&footer.")='filename' or lowcase("&footer.")='sheetname',tranwrd(tranwrd(lowcase("&footer."),'filename','&F'),'sheetname','&A'),"&footer.");
    call symput("header",trim(header));
    call symput("footer",trim(footer));
  run;

  %let WorkBook=%scan(&WorkBookPath.,%sysfunc(countw(&WorkBookPath.,\)),\);

    %* ***********************************************;
    %* get the short DOS name for the workspace folder;

    data _null_;
      rc=filename("inpipe",catx('"','for %I in (',"%sysfunc(pathname(work))",') do echo %~sI'),"pipe");
    run;

    data _null_;
      infile inpipe truncover end=last;
      input @1 data $256. ;
      rc=filename("inpipe","");
      if last then call symput('_shortpath',trim(data));
    run;

    %* *******************************;
    %* tidy up any previous executions;

    data _null_;
      if fileexist("&_shortpath\testx.vbs") then do;
        rc=filename("dump","&_shortpath\testx.vbs");
        rc=fdelete('dump');
        msg=sysmsg();
        if msg ne '' then put msg=;
      end;
      if fileexist("&_shortpath\xmlFile.xml") then do;
        rc=filename("dump","");
        rc=filename("dump","&_shortpath\xmlFile.xml");
        rc=fdelete('dump');
        msg=sysmsg();
        if msg ne '' then put msg=;
        rc=filename("dump","");
      end;
    run;


  %if %sysfunc(fileexist("&WorkBookPath."))=1 %then %do;


    data null;
      file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\testx.vbs";
      put @1 'Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")';
      put @1 'objExcel.Application.Visible = True';
      put @1 'objExcel.Workbooks.open  "' "&WorkBookPath." '"' ;
      %if %str(&onlySheet.) ne %str() %then %do;
        put @1 'onlySheetExisits=False';
        put @1 'for each sheet in objExcel.Workbooks("' "&WorkBook." '").sheets';  
        put @1 'if strcomp(sheet.name,"' "&onlySheet." '",1)=0 then onlySheetExisits=True';
        put @1 'if strcomp(sheet.name,"' "&onlySheet." '",1)=0 then sheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "' "%str(&Header.)" '"';
        put @1 'if strcomp(sheet.name,"' "&onlySheet." '",1)=0 then sheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "' "%str(&Footer.)" '"';
        put @1 'Next';
      %end;
      %else %do;
        put @1 'for each sheet in objExcel.Workbooks("' "&WorkBook." '").sheets';  
        put @1 'sheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "' "%str(&Header.)" '"';
        put @1 'sheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "' "%str(&Footer.)" '"';
        put @1 'Next'; 
      %end;

      put @1 'objExcel.Workbooks("' "&WorkBook." '").save';
      put @1 'objExcel.Workbooks("' "&WorkBook." '").Close';
      put @1 'objExcel.Application.Quit';
      %if %str(&onlySheet.) ne %str() %then %do;
        put @1 'if onlySheetExisits=False then msgbox "Error! Could not find Worksheet: '"&onlySheet."' in Workbook: "' ' & vbcr & ' '" '"&WorkBookPath." '",16,"SAS: '"&SYSMACRONAME"'"';
      %end;

    run;


    x %sysfunc(quote("&_shortpath.\testx.vbs")); 

  %end;
  %else %put %str(ERR)OR: [&SYSMACRONAME.] Unable to open: &WorkBookPath.  - check it exists!;


%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

With DDE you can set the filter in SAS:

```
data _null_;
    FILE CMDS;
    /* select your worksheet */
    put '[workbook.select("your_sheet")]';
    /* select the column range you want to set the filter */
    put '[select("r1c2:r1c5")]';
    /* set filter */
    put '[filter]';
run;
```